# Recursive wget gives 'invalid character is found in given range'

Tags: wget

Trying to recursively get the contents of a directory using

```
wget -r --no-parent [directory URL]
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Warning: Invalid character is found in given range. A specified range MUST 
Warning: have only digits in 'start'-'stop'. The server's response to this 
Warning: request is uncertain.
```

How do I fix this?

URL takes this form:

```
wget -r --no-parent https://prefix.domain.suffix.suffix/microsite/prefix.domain.suffix.suffix/
```

When I leave out the `https://` I get this message from the `wget`:

```
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
```

Followed by:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2016-08-11 14:35:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Can you post the whole command line including the URL you used when that message appeared?

Comment: I'd rather not post the URL if that's alright with you. I'm testing a site for an organization and I've already found one security issue relating to the URL. However, I can reproduce it like this: `wget -r --no-parent https://prefix.domain.suffix.suffix/microsite/prefix.domain.suffix.suffix/` which should be all you need to know? Which... now I think about it I think I understand. The problem seems to be related to another issue I had...

Comment: Fair enough.  I was worried that wget was tripping over some oddness in the URL, but if it's reproducible with a straightforward URL then that's not it.

Comment: Yeah, I can grab files directly (kind of a problem in itself), but I can't do the recursive `wget` part at the moment... though I've certain there's another way that will allow it, so I want to find it.

Comment: Hhhhhhmmm. Interesting, when I leave out the `https://` I get this message from the `wget`: `URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy` followed by: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-08-11 14:35:37 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

Comment: You might want to add this stuff to your question, which just got a lot more interesting :)

Comment: added info to question

Answer (score 0):

Is your `wget` actually symlinked (or hard linked) to `curl`, as in this [similar question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/456606/wget-on-my-mac-doesnt-let-me-do-recursive)

An easy way to check, is to run it with no arguments, like below.

First, on my system I add a link to create the scenario I believe you face, so you don't need to run these commands:

```
$ cd /opt/local/bin
$ ls -l wget curl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  181204 May 30 03:36 curl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  512932 Apr 30 16:42 wget
```

this is the usage error message from wget:

```
$ ./wget
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
Try `wget --help' for more options.
```

I move it aside and create a hard link:

```
$ mv wget wget_save
$ ln curl wget
```

I can confirm it's a link by listing by inode:

```
$ ls -li | egrep '(curl|wget)'
68507780 -rwxr-xr-x     2 root      admin      181204 May 30 03:36 curl
68507780 -rwxr-xr-x     2 root      admin      181204 May 30 03:36 wget
67018610 -rwxr-xr-x     1 root      admin      512932 Apr 30 16:42 wget_save
```

Then I exec that symlinked binary which has the path name 'wget', but you can see that the usage message reveals that it is really a curl binary, not wget.

This is what I'm suggesting you test. Run wget with no arguments:

```
$ ./wget
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

And the cause of the error is that you're using the standalone option `-r` for `wget`, but since the executable is really `curl`, it returns a usage error.

Comment: `[root@fedora ~]# ln /opt/local/bin/curl ./wget
ln: failed to access '/opt/local/bin/curl': No such file or directory`

Comment: Ran `ls -l` in the `/bin` directory which contains `wget`. No symlink (though I did find a broken link to Sublime I need to get rid of).

Comment: it could be a hard link, or perhaps is finding it elsewhere. `which wget` to see where it's finding it in your path, and then `/bin/ls -il /bin | egrep '(wget|curl)'`, where you replace `/bin` with whatever directory you find with the which command. Then you could see that wget and curl have the same inode.

Comment: `13832 -rwxr-xr-x    1 root root      197280 Aug  3 15:36 curl
 1733 -rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      511288 Jun 14 19:01 wget`

Comment: ok, it's not linked to that curl binary. But just run `./wget` with no arguments. Is the resulting usage error showing the program name curl or wget? (And the reason for believing this is that the error message you show is actually in curl, which you can see in the source code here: https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/src/tool_getparam.c#L1660

Comment: `./wget
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try 'wget --help' for more options.` So `wget`, by the looks of things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43825/discussion-between-tim-b-and-amy-t-mcbride).